# Is there a way I can get object's position relative to the origin point(0.0.0)?

Tags: modeling, transforms

If I reset a object's origin (in order to mirror it), is there a way I can somehow get the object's current position relative to origin point(0.0.0) before I reset the object's origin?

EDIT: Basically i want to move car rear panel(the one where car rear lights go) to 0.0.0 to create better tail lights for it) and when the tail lights are created, i want to put that car part(the rear panel) to where it were before i moved it to 0.0.0 whit "set origin" command!

Answer (score 3):

The objects origin is the (0, 0, 0) point of it's data. No matter what object location, rotation or scale is.  An object, the default cube for instance, has one origin, it's location is arbitrary.  We could put the cursor anywhere and change the origin to that point, using transform > origin to cursor, and for all extents and purposes the cube's mesh doesn't move.  What does change tho is the local data (the vertex coordinates) and the object location to match.

The default cube has a vertex with coordinate (-1, -1, -1). If we make the origin point at that vertex' location, the vertex will now have the coordinate, yep you guessed it, (0, 0, 0).  The cube will now have a location of (-1, -1, -1) instead of zero... looks like it hasn't moved, only the little orange dot specifying its origin moved.  Local coordinates is a fundamental of 3D.

Now how does this apply to your car model.  You want to have an origin where x=0 is in the middle of your car from the front.  This will enable you to use mirror effectively.

One way to do this:

Select the tail lights (or the windscreen or something that's centre is the centre of vehicle), go into edit mode, select all verts.  Snap <kbd>shift-s</kbd> cursor to selection.  Look in the 3D cursor panel.  It's the x offset that has put your model out of whack.

[image]

Get out of edit mode.  With just the lights selected, set origin to cursor at this point will put it right in the middle shown in image above, but onlyh for the tail lights.

Or at this point to change origin of all car parts to a centre:

Keep the 3D cursor's X location value and change the Z and Y values to suit, 0 is good.  Now select every object that makes up your car. Object > Transform > origin to 3D cursor.

[image]

Another tip at this point would be to add an empty at cursor location.  Make it the parent of all the car parts. This way moving the empty will move the car as one.

[image]

Comment: Holy god.... I am so grateful for what you just did to me! I think i just found a new god to praise, and i am(or used to be) atheist!

Answer (score 0):

well you can place the cursor to any other object, or active selection..

(Sometimes one uses a "empty" type of object just to get to a specific place but not render such a object, in the right properties pane, object menu you can set exact position of such an empty).

shift S, then put Cursor at.. (make a selection)
After that  pressing space type "set origin" to cursor.
Though note that "set origin" works only in edit mode.
And if you want to snap to another object you have to switch to object mode firs to put your cursor on another object / location.

Comment: This is way complicated... What of this should i do on the "empty/filler" object and which one of this should i do on object(car part) i want to later restore of its location?

Comment: well i was trying to be complete in my answer, as it wasn't really clear what your purpose is. If i understand you correctly, then you should place an empty at (0,0,0). Then do a cursor to target (the empty); you can then set any part of any object in edit mode to that orgin (set origin to cursor).

ea a car part wheel can get the same origin as a car part roof then.
if that's what you want, maybe thats handy for your mirror effects or so i dont know. Just note that there is a lot possible with blender and what seams to you easy, has also a lot other easy possibilities

Comment: Basically i want to move car rear panel(the one where car rear lights go) to 0.0.0 to create better tail lights for it(using mirror modifier)) and when the tail lights are created, i want to put that car part(the rear panel) to where it were before i moved it to 0.0.0 whit "set origin" command!